# Hibernate dialect for Oracle Database 11g?

Tags: oracle, hibernate, oracle11g

Is there a Hibernate dialect for Oracle Database 11g? Or should I use the `org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect` that ships with Hibernate?

Answer (score 117, accepted):

Use the Oracle 10g dialect. Also Hibernate 3.3.2+ is required for recent JDBC drivers (the internal class structure changed - symptoms will be whining about an abstract class).

Dialect of Oracle 11g is same as Oracle 10g (*org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect*). Source: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-optional-dialects

Comment: Unfortunately does not help for "ORA-01754: a table may contain only one column of type LONG".

Comment: I have a problem with specific reserved function INTERVAL.. e.g " @Formula(" SYSDATE - INTERVAL '1' HOUR * SHOW_LIMIT_HOURS ") " . I don´t know it is could generate some issue, but seem to be a good solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26907699/1488761

Answer (score 14):

According to [supported databases](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/SupportedDatabases), Oracle 11g is not officially supported. Although, I believe you shouldn't have any problems using `org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect`.

Comment: Mind that `org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect` is deprecated ( http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/dialect/OracleDialect.html). You should use the Oracle 10g dialect.

Comment: Oracle 11 is now supported

Comment: As @MJB pointed out Oracle 11 is supported. The missing part is : it is supported with org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect class [link](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-optional-dialects) (applies to hiernate 4.x too)

Answer (score 4):

We had a problem with the (deprecated) dialect `org.hibernate.dialect.Oracledialect`    and  Oracle 11g database using    `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto = validate`       mode.

With this dialect Hibernate was unable to found the sequences (because the implementation of the     `getQuerySequencesString()`     method, that returns this query:

`"select sequence_name from user_sequences;"`

for which the execution returns an empty result from database).

Using the dialect     `org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle9iDialect`       , or greater, solves the problem, due to a different implementation of      `getQuerySequencesString()`        method:

`"select sequence_name from all_sequences  union  select synonym_name from all_synonyms us, all_sequences asq  where asq.sequence_name = us.table_name and asq.sequence_owner = us.table_owner;"`

that returns all the sequences if executed, instead.

Answer (score 2):

At least in case of EclipseLink 10g and 11g differ. Since 11g it is not recommended to use first_rows hint for pagination queries.

See ["Is it possible to disable jpa hints per particular query"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36840776/is-it-possible-to-disable-jpa-hints-per-particular-query). 
Such a query should not be used in 11g.

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT /*+ FIRST_ROWS */ a.*, ROWNUM rnum  FROM (
    SELECT * FROM TABLES INCLUDING JOINS, ORDERING, etc.) a
  WHERE ROWNUM <= 10 )
WHERE rnum > 0;
```

But there can be other nuances.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using WL 10 use the following:

`org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect`

Answer (score 0):

Providing latest development on this.
SpringBoot-3.1.4 doesn't require Dialect and JDBC driver to explicitly configure. It's take care of automatically.

You can remove following lines from application.properties

```
spring.datasource.driver.class-name=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
```

Only following properties are sufficient:

```
spring.datasource.url=****
spring.datasource.username=***
spring.datasource.password=****
```