# Is Hibernate 3.0 compatible with Oracle 11g?

Tags: oracle, hibernate, oracle11g

Is Hibernate 3.0 compatible with Oracle 11g?

---

in hibernate-3.0.jar we have OracleDialect which according to documentation,compatible with any Oracle version.

So with Oracle 11g I suppose OracleDialect should work.

Could you plz share your views regarding my opinion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there isn't hibernate dialect for Oracle11g in [dialect list](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/api/org/hibernate/dialect/package-summary.html), but you can use 10g dialect according to this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4369944/hibernate-dialect-for-oracle-database-11g).