# ORA-01722 invalid number error with oracle database in hibernate query language

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

I am using query

```
select x 
from table1 x 
order by x.it desc
```

It is working good when I use it with Postgres but whenever i change the database and start to use oracle it is throwing an error that is,

> ERROR -- ORA-01722: invalid number
>   org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query

Comment: Are you changing the database dialect also?

Comment: Show us your table definition. What is the type of the `it` column?

Comment: I have changed the database and my software is working good with all the HQL query , only this query is throwing an error while executing

Comment: It is x.id and it number type in oracle

Comment: I asked about database **dialect**? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4369944/hibernate-dialect-for-oracle-database-11g

Comment: org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect for 11g and I am using this dialect

Comment: Turn on SQL logging, see what exact query is being generated by Hibernate and try to find what's wrong with it.