# Is it possible to disable jpa hints per particular query?

Tags: java, oracle, jpa, oracle11g

JPA, and in my particular case eclipselink, generates `/*+ FIRST_ROWS */` in case of using `query.setFirstResult()/query.setMaxResults()`:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT /*+ FIRST_ROWS */ a.*, ROWNUM rnum  FROM (
    SELECT * FROM TABLES INCLUDING JOINS, ORDERING, etc.) a
  WHERE ROWNUM <= 10 )
WHERE rnum > 0;
```

That forces Oracle to use nested loops instead of hash-joins. In general is has seance, but in my particular case it dramatically decrease performance.

Is it possible to disable hint usage/generation for a particular query?

Comment: why u need to use setFirstResult?

Comment: explain plan without /* + FIRST_ROWS*/ really better?

Comment: nested loop is not a really bad thing, and HASH join is not a really good choice either when u got only a few thousands row

Comment: AFAIK Eclipselink has something like setHint method. If you use Hibernate, you should contact Hibernate support. http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.4/jpa/extensions/q_sql_hint.htm

Comment: @Thomas setFirstResult is used for pagination. I agree that in general nested loop might be better then hash join. I believe that's the point, why oracle choose it for my request.

Comment: @HAYMbl4 in my case it's 100 times better.

Comment: @ibre5041 Yes, there's such method, however I need to disable (remove) automatically generated hint.

Comment: What happen then you call this method? Is `first_rows` somehow merged into it? According to this: http://www.celinio.net/techblog/?p=1767 (referring Oracle bug 374136, first_rows should no more be needed for 11g and later).  So maybe you should report a bug in Hibernate. (first_rows should no more be used for pagination, generally it still makes sense- of course)

Comment: Anyway `first_rows` hint is deprecated and should not be used at all. It was replaced by `FIRST_ROWS_n` set of hints. http://stanford.edu/dept/itss/docs/oracle/10g/server.101/b10752/optimops.htm: Note: Using heuristics sometimes leads the query optimizer to generate a plan with a cost that is significantly larger than the cost of a plan without applying the heuristic. FIRST_ROWS is available for backward compatibility and plan stability; use FIRST_ROWS_n instead.

Comment: @san Could you please paste in both plan: with first_rows and without first_rows hint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @ibre5041 told, FIRST_ROWS hint is deprecated, in context of Oracle, FIRST_ROWS(N) should be used instead of it. In my case neither FIRST_ROW nor FIRST_ROW(N) is actually needed, so in order to tell eclipselink not to use outdated stuff, it's possible to specify oracle version within persistence.xml:

```
<property name="eclipselink.target-database" value="org.eclipse.persistence.platform.database.oracle.Oracle11Platform" />
```

After adding this, I got strange error:
[Could not initialize class org.eclipse.persistence.platform.database.oracle.Oracle11Platform](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=306309)
However, after I put ojdbcN.jar to domain/lib/ext the error has gone.

As a result, eclipselink generates query without FIRST_ROW hint, and Oracle uses better plan.